# Is my server hacked?

Tags: security, process, cpu-usage

I just noticed a high CPU usage on my server in the last few days and checked the processes. It appears that these 2 process below is consuming my CPU usage:

```
30741 www-data  20   0   89556  10264      4 S 213.6  0.1  26636:45 /tmp/sshm -c /tmp/.u
18575 www-data  20   0  725948  10244     56 S 212.3  0.1   6608:57 /tmp/.FILE/stak/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /tmp/.FILE/stak /tmp/.FILE/stak/xmrig -o 195.22.126.117:443 -u 45ENzNUptUrV8nLM2Cwwwb1r98M7ZPocmdsmg1SKWAL6b8DJQcU3+
```

Is my server hacked or,as I read on some other places, being used for crypto-currency mining? What should I do in this situation?

I would really appreciate any help/support. Thank you!

Comment: If it isn't your [miner](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) process running as `www-data` (httpd) from `/tmp`, then your server is quite possibly hacked.

Comment: I read in other articles about the Jenkins servers (which mine is) issue that turn them into XMRIG mining slaves - which can be seen in "/tmp/.FILE/stak/xmrig -o". Does anyone know how to stop & remove this from the server?

Comment: Put the server into single user runlevel. Block the IP in your log on the FW. Kill processes. Remove their files. Patch the vulnerability and return to normal op. This way you may be able to avoid rebuilding.

Comment: Your server is hacked **and** being used for crypto-currency mining.

Comment: @immibis: clearly, yes.

Comment: @ajeh: blocking the IP doesn't help. any idea why?

Comment: The intruder has probably done something to make the system give you false information about either the system's firewall configuration, or about the source IP of the intruder. This is why dsstorefile said you'll have to restore from backup: **you don't know for sure the full scope of the intruders' actions** without a very labor-intensive investigation. Restoring from backup and/or rebuilding is usually easier, and gives you a strong guarantee that **no** intruder's tools are left hidden in the system.

Comment: You need to block their IPs on a FW other than local of course! This machine is compromised.

Answer (score 3):

Just by looking at your posted output, I can see a cryptocurrency miner `xmrig` running.  If you did not intend to launch that process, someone with sufficient access was able to.

You posted two processes, each of them look very suspicious:

```
30741 www-data  20   0   89556  10264      4 S 213.6  0.1  26636:45 /tmp/sshm -c /tmp/.u
```

This is a process owned by `www-data` running an executable, `/tmp/sshm`,  with the argument `/tmp/.u`.  You should be able to inspect those two files to determine if they are malicious or not.

```
18575 www-data  20   0  725948  10244     56 S 212.3  0.1   6608:57 /tmp/.FILE/stak/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path /tmp/.FILE/stak /tmp/.FILE/stak/xmrig -o 195.22.126.117:443 -u 45ENzNUptUrV8nLM2Cwwwb1r98M7ZPocmdsmg1SKWAL6b8DJQcU3+
```

This is another process owned by `www-data`, and this is the cryptocurrency miner.  It has installed itself into `/tmp/.FILE`.  If you did not install and run this, then you are most certainly exploited somewhere.

If those processes are malicious, you want to kill them so they stop running.  You would then want to look for the entry point of these malicious files.  Since they are owned by `www-data`, you most likely have a legitimate process on this server running as that user, possibly a web server or application, that is allowing the creation and execution of these files.

You need to find that entry point as soon as you can and fix it, or the malicious files will probably just come back again.  Looking at your log files should help.  Make sure to check anything that the `www-data` user is able to do.  Double check your web server and/or web applications to make sure they are not allowing the installing and execution of these files.

One server hardening step I have seen to mitigate these kind of issues is to [not allow exec from `/tmp` at all](https://serverfault.com/questions/72356): `mount -o noexec,remount /tmp`.

Comment: I understand the hedging, but I'm confident in saying that nobody has ever installed a cryptocurrency miner in a hidden directory in `/tmp` and then run it under their web server's account

Comment: Whilst noexec  in /tmp and /var/tmp would be pretty a good idea, many installers, including Debian APT, depend on having exec there. You will break things.